# Material UI theme override issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code, I am trying to override the theme of the Material UI react, But somehow it is not getting override, I am getting default colors only. Here is my code.

I have installed proper libraries also, In package JSON i have added `"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",` and `"@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",` Which are required. Cleaned install and restart, It looks simple but still not working.

```
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import React from "react";

function App() {

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Button color="primary">Primary</Button>
            <Button color="secondary">Secondary</Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}


const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            // Purple and green play nicely together.
            main: "#000000",
        },
        secondary: {
            // This is green.A700 as hex.
            main: '#11cb5f',
        },
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            textPrimary: {
                color: "#efefef"
            },
            text: {
                color: '#000000',
            },
            containedPrimary: {
                backgroundColor: "#9f9f9f"
            }
        },
    },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: What ins't working exactly ? Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-ramanujan-jviiw?file=/src/App.js:84-88.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the createMuiTheme import, and you're importing ThemeProvider from the wrong folder.

Try this:

`import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

You shouldn't really need the @material-ui/styles package at all. Also, make sure to define `theme` before using the variable in `App`.